# Using facebook app to login to a website

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I have a web app and I want to use the native facebook login to register users to my web application.

The login is currently with the plain old facebook js sdk, I want the facebook login button to trigger FB app and return an Auth Response.

Is it possible?

Comment: Your question is not clear! Pls explain what currently are you doing and what you want to do now

Comment: I'm using Facebook Connect via JS SDK in order to login users to my website. (just to get their emails). But the users who use my web-app mostly use the FB native app and are not surfing the FB website. that means they are logged in the FB app but not on the browser. I don't want them to login in the browser when they are already connected via the native app. I want to convert my FB connect to FB native app connect. IS IT POSSIBLE?